# How to redirect from one port to another?

Tags: apache

I've a domain on which I'm running two different web applications at different ports.

- A Java web application on http://example:8888/foo
- A PHP website on http://example:8080/bar

The requirement is, if an user tries to access the root of http://example:8888 or http://example:8080, then the user should be redirected to http://example:8888/foo.

How can I achieve this requirement?

Comment: Who is listening on these ports? Is it Apache both times?

Comment: @Pekka Yes, it is apache for both.

Answer (score 0):

mod_rewrite can achieve this easily, you will be using 301 redirects

> RewriteEngine On
>
> RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.com$ [NC]
>
> RewriteRule ^/$ http://example.com:8888/foo [R=301,L]

Make sure this is added in the vhost config section of both sites.